# Browser that doesn't support cookies

Tags: web-browser, cookies

I am looking for a browser that doesn't support cookies at all. I need it for some security testing of my website.

I am not interested in an ordinary browser with turned off cookies, it isn't the solution for me.

Is it possible to find it in the modern world?

**EDIT:** I am using Windows 10, but I will be able to install any on Virtual Machine.

Comment: I'm confused.  Most people that would potentially visit your website would use a browser that supported cookies.

Comment: @rrirower I want to check my site with cookieless="AutoDetect" and cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" options. Especially I am interested, how browser without support cookies at all will work in the last mode.

Comment: Isn't Chrome's incognito mode what ignores cookies?

Comment: @Mjh Nope, Chrome in incognito mode works with cookies but clear them when you close the browser.

Comment: So what you're after is when your site sends the cookies, browser is supposed to simply drop them and every next request is then cookieless? Why not just use `cURL` from command line if all you need to do is testing?

Comment: @Mjh It doesn't drop them during next request. I can login on some page and browser in incognito mode keeps my session (via cookies).

Comment: For "human" testing, personally, I'd use Chrome and install an extension that removes cookies for me, automatically (there are a few at the store). Alternatively, there's ctrl + shift + delete in Chrome so you can quickly delete cookies yourself. For automated tests, there's always `cURL`. Would that get you going towards what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mjh My purpose is to test UseDeviceProfile mode. I need a browser that doesn't support cookies at all. I can simulate this and have some idea how webapp will behave but I want to validate it.

Comment: Not supporting cookies is **equal** to not sending them upon every request to your website. To achieve that with **existing** browsers, all you need to do is to remove those cookies after each request. Easiest way for this is to 1) delete them manually or 2) use one of existing extensions that does exactly that so you can just click around and have 0 cookies stored (and consequently, 0 cookies sent every time you browse). Therefore, the software you need *exists*, it's just up to you whether you want to use it or if you want to waste valuable development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It doesn't drop them during next request. I can login on some page and browser in incognito mode keeps my session (via cookies)*

Safari kind of supports this. Every private tab in Safari starts from scratch regarding cookies. In Chrome and Firefox, if you open a private window and login somewhere and then open another tab in that private window, you are logged in to that site in both tabs. However, in Safari, in the same scenario you aren't logged in in the second tab.

To achieve what you are looking for, open a private window in Safari and then when you click a link, open that link in a new tab. When you click the next link, do it in a new tab. Etc.

Comment: Thank you, @d-b. 
Frankly, I needed 5 min to understand why I asked this question 6 years ago.